# How to extend base Number type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend base Number type and add some custom prototype:

Core files looks like this:

**tsconfig.json:**

```
...

"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "types"
]

...
```

**types/number.d.ts:**

```
export {}

declare global {
    interface Number {
        isInt() : () => any
    }
}
```

**number.extension.ts:**

```
Number.prototype.isInt = function() {
    return (Math.round(this) == this)
}
```

---

And when I'm trying to compile, I'm getting errors:

```
Error: number.extensions.ts:16:18 - error TS2339: Property 'isInt' does not exist on type 'Number'.
[ng] 16 Number.prototype.isInt = function() {
[ng]                     ~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts:395:5 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'trimMiddle'.
[ng] 395     trimMiddle: () => any;
[ng]         ~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts:396:5 - error TS2411: Property 'anchor' of type '(name: string) => string' is not assignable to string index type '() => any'.
[ng] 396     [x: string]: () => any;
[ng]         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts:396:5 - error TS2411: Property 'charAt' of type '(pos: number) => string' is not assignable to string index type '() => any'.
[ng] 396     [x: string]: () => any;
[ng]         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts:396:5 - error TS2411: Property 'charCodeAt' of type '(index: number) => number' is not assignable to string index type '() => any'.
[ng] 396     [x: string]: () => any;
```

... and much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's works ([ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=37&pln=8&pc=44#code/PTCmA8AcHsCcBcAEBvAvokiCuA7AxtALag5ICW5OisoAhgDaIEAmoAUCK3vbTYgOb1oAIwYoMwbPiIlylanUYt2iVYjKlQsAGa08oRADkshYVpRs1V9QGcAkqQBciABQBKRAF4AfKuHRoejocSzVUDmB0TFwCYlJ1eRoxZTY2Y1MtADpIWGh4PIBPSFBMsnt4z0RtGPgyaBx3R39A4IsrGngsWCoXAFlaeAALTNzcZhd0s1gXIbK3D09K2Zs3NnC2IKRwZ0nzSoBGAAYAbg3QJAKdkymvRCPMgCZTghwbFsyhfhdwUvL4dw8mHgsCw7BebyCH2gXwKvwc-3mEiqDBs7CAA)):

```
export {}
declare global {
    interface Number {
        isInt: () =>  boolean // type is 'boolean', not 'any'
    }
}

Number.prototype.isInt = function():boolean {
    // we must cast Number to number via Number(this)
    return (Math.round(Number(this)) == this) 
}

let x: Number = 10;
let y: Number = 10.2;
console.log(x.isInt()) // true
console.log(y.isInt()) // false
```

Comment: Yes. Problem was with cache